# Referential integrity from database A to database B

Tags: sql-server, referential-integrity

I have two Windows applications, each of them is using its own database. I need table, where will be data common for both applications and I need referential integrity. Is there better solution than creating triggers in shared database and pushing changes to both databases?

Comment: I assume you've been downvoted because this question could be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  But without a comment we'll never know...   That's one approach.  Another is to move both apps into one db (perhaps using schema's to separate the tables that aren't shared).  If you don't need live updates you could schedule an SSIS job to periodically sync the data.

Comment: Another solution is to use publish/subscribe replication. The problem is that this and also jobs are not supported in Express version. I think I will have to omit referential integrity or use only single database...